# How to locate "Asset found on hard drive (blender-kit)"

Tags: asset, blenderkit

I was downloading an Apple basket mesh via Blender kit.

I couldn't tell if the download completed, as the download stopped at some point in time.

I have decided to try the download again and it says ASSET FOUND ON HARD DRIVE.

How do I locate it on the hard drive?

Comment: Look at the addon's settings under Edit > Preferences > Addons. Under Windows, the Global Files Directory in the addon's Preferences section shows the location where the Blenderkit files appear and I assume it's the same on Macs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows:
- This PC
- Windows(C:)
- Users
- (Whatever the name of your user is)
- Blenderkit_data
- Models

Answer (score 1):

Before BlenderKit add-on starts download it checks if the asset is available locally. If so it starts importing it. However if the files are corrupted for some reason (broken previous download, or other reasons), it gives this error `Asset not found on hard drive`. Add-on then deletes the broken asset but does not start new download.

To fix this issue you should be able to just drag the asset into the scene again. This will then start the download as the broken asset is no longer available on disk.

I understand that this can be little bit confusing and process could be more practival if re-download was initiated automatically. Having this automatic re-download on our TODO list.